# Nuallable datatype becomes null in wcf when adding as webreference

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a  service data contract as shown below

```
 [DataContract]
    public class CandidateResquest
    {
       [DataMember]

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CandidateDOB { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string CandidateFirstName { get; set; }
     }
```

My Service method is shown below

```
public CandidateResponseBase UploadCandidate(CandidateResquest candidateResquest)
{
   //Details goes here
}
```

From a different application domain I am calling this service.When I am adding  as a Servicereference it passing CandidateDOB  from client to service but when I am adding as a webreference it is passing null.My client application is a simple console application.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you instantiate the CandidateDOB property? Any property that hasn't been directly instantiated will be null.

Comment: yes I did.Candidate.CandidateResquest objCandRequest = new Candidate.CandidateResquest();
            string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
           objCandRequest.CandidateDOB = DateTime.ParseExact("21/09/1983", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            objCandRequest.CandidateFirstName = "Azaruddin";

Comment: Is it something to with Specified variable ... i.e. before making the call if it allows set CandidateResquest.CandidateDOBSpecified = true; .. If this solves your problem please let me know i will add that as answer.

Comment: Thanks.Gr8 answer.It works correctly.

Comment: I have added my comment as answer.Please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Please add

> CandidateResquest.CandidateDOBSpecified = true;

Before calling the web method.